# CUDA direct access to DirectX 11 backbuffer

Tags: cuda, directx

Is it possible to access the DX11 backbuffer directly through CUDA? So instead of copying the data back to the CPU and then sending back to the device to render as a texture, I could just access the buffer directly in my kernel?

This seems to be possible in DirectCompute so I wonder if I can do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Look at DirectX Interoperability in the CUDA Programming Guide.

Comment: is it able to Direct write to OpenGL default BackBuffer's ColorAttachment(GL_BACK) by CUDA from kernel ?